# Apache Spark move/rename succefully processed files

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I would like to use spark streaming (1.1.0-rc2 Java-API) to process some files, and move/rename them once the processing is done successfully in order to push them to other jobs.

I thought about using the file path included in the name of generated RDDs ([newAPIHadoopFile](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.1.0-rc2/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala#L640)), but how can we determine a successful end of processing of a file?

Also not sure this the right way to achieve it so any ideas are welcome.

EDIT: 
Here is some pseudo code to be more clear :

```
logs.foreachRDD(new Function2<JavaRDD<String>, Time, Void>() {
 @Override
 public Void call(JavaRDD<String> log, Time time) throws Exception {
    String fileName=log.name();
    String newlog=Process(log);
    SaveResultToFile(newlog, time);

    //are we done with the file so we can move it ????

    return null;
}
```

});

Comment: What do you mean by processing a file here?

Comment: @SeanOwen basically, I am creating enriched versions of corresponding RDDs (each line) by applying some transformations, then write results into an output dir

Comment: How do you not know then when you're done? your code finishes an manually writes the file no?

Comment: Why do you want to use spark streaming for processing files?

Comment: @jkgeyti I have an input directory where I receive a live stream (large number of small files) from external sources, so why not take advantage of Spark's streaming abilities 'high-throughput, fault-tolerant stream processing of live data streams'?

Comment: @SeanOwen I've edited the post hoping to be more clear

Answer (score 0):

You aren't guaranteed that the input is backed by an HDFS file. But it doesn't seem like you need that given your question. You create a new file and write something to it. When the write completes, you're done. Move it with other HDFS APIs.

Comment: Actually I need to move the original file (the one used to generate the RDDs)